# Finding out how much of a total amount each variable represents?

Tags: java

I am trying to find out how much of the total amount variable 1 is responsible for and how much of the total cost variable 2 is responsible for. I have attached an image of my source code so far

the assignment instructions are: The program will then calculate the total of all the expenses, what each person should pay if the costs were divided equally, and how much each friend actually paid. If one person paid less than the other, then they will owe their friend some money.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Trip {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

double flight, hotel, meals, tour, total, owes;
String name1, name2;
double Lisa, Bart;
double input1, input2, input3, input4;

Lisa = 1;
Bart = 2;

System.out.print("Enter the first name: ");

name1 = keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter the second name: ");

name2 = keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter cost of flights: ");

flight = keyboard.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Who paid for the flights: Enter 1 for Lisa or 2 for Bart ");
input1 = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter cost of hotel: ");

hotel = keyboard.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Who paid for the hotel: Enter 1 for Lisa or 2 for Bart ");

input2 = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter cost of tour: ");

tour = keyboard.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Who paid for the tour: Enter 1 for Lisa or 2 for Bart ");

input3 = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter cost of meals: ");

meals = keyboard.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Who paid for the meals: Enter 1 for Lisa or 2 for Bart ");

input4 = keyboard.nextInt();


total = flight + hotel + meals + tour;

System.out.printf("Total bill for trip: %.2f \n", total);

owes = total / 2;

System.out.printf("Each person owes: %.2f", owes);
```

}
}

Comment: If Lisa + Bart = total, then Bart = total - Lisa.  This is simple algebra.  You should be able to apply this to solve your problem.

Comment: Hello, I assigned Lisa = 1 and Bart = 2 at the start so when I do Bart = total - Lisa it just subtracts one from the total. I think my professor wants me to use the if else statement since the rest of the questions have involved that. Do you know how I would approach this using the if else statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have two people **Max** and **Simon**. You could do something like below where you first find the amount owed by **Max** using your logic. And then to find the amount owed by **Simon** you just use `totalCost - amountMaxOwes`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Trip {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the first name:");
    String nameOne = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the second name:");
    String nameTwo = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter cost of flights:");
    double flightsCost = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.printf("Who paid for the flights? Enter 1 for %s or 2 for %s:", nameOne, nameTwo);
    int whoPaidFlights = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter cost of hotel:");
    double hotelCost = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.printf("Who paid for the hotel? Enter 1 for %s or 2 for %s:", nameOne, nameTwo);
    int whoPaidHotel = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter cost of tour:");
    double tourCost = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.printf("Who paid for the tour? Enter 1 for %s or 2 for %s:", nameOne, nameTwo);
    int whoPaidTour = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter cost of meals:");
    double mealsCost = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.printf("Who paid for the meals? Enter 1 for %s or 2 for %s:", nameOne, nameTwo);
    int whoPaidMeals = scanner.nextInt();

    double totalCost = flightsCost + hotelCost + tourCost + mealsCost;
    System.out.printf("Total bill for trip: %.2f \n", totalCost);

    // This stuff can be moved to a more appropriate place if you want to
    double personOnePaid = 0;
    if(whoPaidFlights == 1) personOnePaid += flightsCost;
    if(whoPaidHotel == 1) personOnePaid += hotelCost;
    if(whoPaidTour == 1) personOnePaid += tourCost;
    if(whoPaidMeals == 1) personOnePaid += mealsCost;

    double personTwoPaid = totalCost - personOnePaid;

    System.out.printf("%s owes: %.2f \n", nameOne, personOnePaid);
    System.out.printf("%s owes: %.2f \n", nameTwo, personTwoPaid);
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter the first name: Max
Enter the second name: Simon
Enter cost of flights: 299.34
Who paid for the flights? Enter 1 for Max or 2 for Simon: 1
Enter cost of hotel: 300.40
Who paid for the hotel? Enter 1 for Max or 2 for Simon: 2
Enter cost of tour: 55.00
Who paid for the tour? Enter 1 for Max or 2 for Simon: 1
Enter cost of meals: 314.15
Who paid for the meals? Enter 1 for Max or 2 for Simon: 1
Total bill for trip: 968.89 
Max owes: 668.49 
Simon owes: 300.40
```